# Cheapest (and hopefully fastest) option for family to transfer from CDG to ORY

Tags: budget, transit, family, cdg, ory

My husband and two young daughters (6 & 3) are needing to get to ORY from CGD for a connecting flight that leaves 6 hours after we land.  I have ready about Air France Bus, which sounds the most stress free but for 84 EU sounds expensive.  Are there any recommendations for cheaper but just as stress free options that might (by some miracle) cost less?

Comment: This sounds dangerously close to a shopping question to me http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/. Might it not be better to edit it into a general "options for travel from A to B" question?

Comment: Have you considered [Uber](https://www.uber.com/cities/paris)? They advertize 20 eur + 30 eur from ORLY to city center and then to CDG which is way below the air france bus and the taxi option. You might want to give them a call. (Disclaimer, I've never used Uber before nor am I affiliated with them, I just read about them and this sounds like an interesting option).

Comment: @pnuts as I said, I have no prior experience with them. It quoted 50 euros which I consider way below the 90 euros a taxi would cost for the comparable 'private, from one place directly to another' ride. Even if it's 60, it's still a 30 euro save.

Comment: @StephenKennedy On the contrary, the answer to “options from A to B” would be the right page on http://adp.fr/ whereas an answer to a specific situation (X hours, children) is a specific question that we can answer with specific expertise.

Answer (score 5):

By public transport, the most stress-free by far is the direct Air France bus.

It's a little cheaper and still not too stressful to take the RER B line across Paris and to Antony where you change for the [Orlyval](http://www.orlyval.com/eu/index_eu.htm) shuttle. Buy combined tickets at CDG. The [ticket price](http://www.orlyval.com/achat.htm) is 54.20€ (children under 4 travel free). There is good signage all the way. Most trains from CDG stop at Antony but check the screens at the station to confirm. If there's a strike or other [traffic disruptions on RER B](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/trafic/trafic.php?cat=2), take the Air France bus.

You can also take [RER B](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61874/rer-b/) to the Denfert-Rochereau stop in Paris and change there for the [Orlybus](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61848/orlybus/) bus service. At CDG, buy tickets for Paris, and then buy Orlybus tickets at the bus stop. The transfer is fairly painless even with luggage. The total fare is €48.85 — this option is cheaper for adults but not so much for children because as far as I can tell Orlybus has no reduced fare (I think children under 4 do travel free however). The only advantage of this option is that you get to spend a few minutes in Paris ([Denfert is a nice spot to have a croissant in a café](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/transfer-from-paris-cdg-to-ory/17465#17465)), but this is probably not convenient with children.

I think you can get all the way through Paris for €5.10 per person by a combination of local buses and the metro (there may even be a €3.40 option), but that's not something I'd do with luggage let alone children.

Answer (score 1):

Public transport options could be a bit cheaper but might not qualify as “stress free” for you. You would need some combination of RER and buses with at least one connection in the center of Paris. Six hours is plenty of time so there is no need to be really worried but I can imagine that it could be quite stressful to find your way through an unknown city with bags and kids. Unfortunately, you still need to buy four tickets so you would not save *that* much money compared to the Air France bus.

Taxi might actually be a good option for you. For an individual, it's more expensive but because you must effectively multiply the price of other options by four, it would still be competitive for a family. I am not sure of the exact price, however. There are some private shuttle services too (main difference is that you have to book them in advance and they can't wait at the taxi stand) but they do not seem cheaper.

Air France cars, taxi and private shuttles should all take about the same time and are very dependent on traffic but with 6 hours between the flights I would not worry.

See also [Transfers between Paris and its airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/transfers-between-paris-and-its-airports) and [Transfer from Paris CDG to ORY](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/transfer-from-paris-cdg-to-ory?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

i would highly recommend the use of public transportations. it's cheap and fast. Use the RER and ORLYVAL. Be only carefull of strikes, so if is anounced, plan to use taxi. It is expensive and highly depends on traffic conditions. (rush hours, accidents...). From CDG to ORY, a smart driver won't get stucked but it will cost you high $$$.

hope it help

André (from France)